# GCOM-C / SGLI L3 Chlorophyll-a concentration (V2) satellite data

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, gui

I'm doing research on chlorophyll using GCOM-C / SGLI L3 Chlorophyll-a concentration (V2) satellite data. And I want to make two UI designs.
First design I want to use Select to select the month that you want to see the information.
But I had a problem because I could not make the select functions according to the desired concept.
Here I attach the source code that I have created.
Could you help me please to solve my problem?
Your answer will help me in research.

```
var initIndex = 'Month';
var indexUrl = ui.url.get('index', initIndex);
ui.url.set('index', indexUrl);

var Month = ['Januari','Februari','Maret','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Agustus','September','Oktobor','November','Desember']
var select = ui.Select({
  items: Month, value: ui.url.get('index'), style : {stretch: 'horizontal'}
});
select.onChange (optionChange)

// Set a place holder.
select.setPlaceholder('Pilih Bulan')

function setParams() {
  ui.url.set('Month', MonthSelect.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like you are trying to synchronize a Selection widget with the URL parameters. Here is an example of how to do that:

```js
// Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

/*******************************************************************************
 * Model *
 ******************************************************************************/

var Month = ['Januari','Februari','Maret','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Agustus','September','Oktobor','November','Desember'];

/*******************************************************************************
 * Components *
 ******************************************************************************/

var MonthSelect = ui.Select({
  items: Month,
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal'}
});

/*******************************************************************************
 * Behaviors *
 ******************************************************************************/

function setUrlParam() {
  ui.url.set('month', MonthSelect.getValue());
}
MonthSelect.onChange(setUrlParam);

/*******************************************************************************
 * Initialization *
 ******************************************************************************/

// Set a place holder.
MonthSelect.setPlaceholder('Pilih Bulan');

// If the month is specified as a URL parameter, use it to update the select widget.
if (ui.url.get('month') && Month.indexOf(ui.url.get('month')) >= 0) {
  MonthSelect.setValue(ui.url.get('month'));
}

// Display the select widget in the console.
print(MonthSelect);
```

Example script:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/97dfc6ea1371aba1836fa170ba1bb536#month=Agustus;

Comment: Thankyou Mr, I am still confused about how to function it. If I don't use the Url, what will I change the function?
Because as long as the url data doesn't exist yet

Comment: My code is like this and when I choose the month I want to appear, I can't 
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d4f52a0326c13e6b3f31bcccbf32c264